# How to attach JavaScript on click event of GridView's EditButton/DeleteButton?

Tags: javascript, gridview

I have a GridView which has EditButton and DeleteButton enabled. When the user clicks either of the buttons, I want to execute a custom JavaScript codes. In an ordinary Button, we can accomplish this by setting OnClientClick="MyJSFunction();".

Thanks!

Comment: are you using a specific javascript library to do this or "rolling your own"?

Comment: @Shakakai - No, I don't use any...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

here i consider this is your last column in Grid-view

```
<asp:CommandField ShowEditButton="true" ButtonType="Image" HeaderText="Edit" EditImageUrl="~/Images/edit.png" UpdateImageUrl="~/Images/update.png" CancelImageUrl="~/Images/cancel.jpg" >
</asp:CommandField>
```

and write following code in code-behind which will call your custom java-script function.

```
Protected Sub gvSectionTimePeriod_RowDataBound(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.Web.UI.WebControls.GridViewRowEventArgs) Handles gvSectionTimePeriod.RowDataBound

  Dim iIndex As Integer = //here write index of yr last column
  CType(e.Row.Cells(iIndex).Controls(0), ImageButton).Attributes.Add("onclick", "return ValidateData();")

End Sub
```

and here yr java-script part

```
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
    function ValidateData()
    {
        //your code
    }
</script>
```

Comment: It works on EditButton, but when I use it on DeleteButton, an exception is thrown: Unable to cast object of type 'System.Web.UI.LiteralControl' to type 'System.Web.UI.WebControls.Button'. Any idea?

Comment: see e.Row.Cells(iIndex).Controls(0) means it is for Edit button.for delete button index may be 1 or 2.so change the index in .Controls(1 or 2 ) and try again.

Comment: Hm, it seems like there is a LiteralControl between them. Maybe Microsoft put it there on purpose. Who knows, Web Forms is so mysterious!